# How to get inset box-shadow work on thead in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, css

I have created this [very simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/etrfu/3/) to reproduce the issue. I does what's expected in firefox but not in chrome. Is there a workaround to achieve the same purpose ?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<table  cellpadding="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Adskldj</th>
            <th>dfsdfd</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>Adskldj</th><th>dfsdfd</th></tr>
        <tr><th>Adskldj</th><th>dfsdfd</th></tr>
        <tr><th>Adskldj</th><th>dfsdfd</th></tr>
        <tr><th>Adskldj</th><th>dfsdfd</th></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the CSS

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td, th {
    border-top: 1px solid #888;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
    padding: 30px;
}
thead {
    background-color: #DDD;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that box-shadow needs to be on a block level element. Hence it not working on a thead.

I have tried to find the spec, but still. Block Level.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using the CSS3 fancy-ness by bypassing table tags and using css display properties instead, making a class for each native table-element and applying it to a <div> or other element.

CSS such as:

```
.row{
    display:table-row;
}
.cell{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

etc.

This allows some nice effects that are not possible using regular tables.